# jQuery dynamic form adding widgets

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to make a simple UI for a MongoDB aggregation query builder. Basically a user needs to click on a dropdown option (Group By, Sort, Limit, etc) then another field should popup next to it to select the variable.

The problem is that the field is displaying multiple times after the first drop down is selected.

[Group By][New Field][New Field][New Field]

The [New Field] is appearing multiple times, and I can't figure out why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

aggStageDropDown = function(counter) {
    return "<select id='aggStage'" + counter + "'>\
        <option value='unselected'>(Select One)</option>\
        <option value='group'>Group</option>\
        <option value='match'>Match</option>\
        <option value='unwind'>Unwind</option>\
        <option value='sort'>Sort</option>\
    </select>\
    "; 

}

varDropDown = function(counter) {
    return "<select>\
        <option value='var1'>var1</option>\
        <option value='var2'>var2</option>\
        <option value='var3'>var3</option>\
    </select>\
    ";
}

// First elements in HTML
$("body").append("<div class='container'></div>")
$(".container").append("<button class='addGroup'>Add More Fields</button>");

var counter = 1;

$(".addGroup").click(function() {

    // Add a <div>, this will contain each group of form elements.
    $(".container").append(function(){
        return "<div class='controlGroup' id='aggStage" + counter + "'></div>";
    });

    // For each .controlGroup, add removeControlGroup button and add drop-down menu.
    $("#aggStage" + counter).html(function(counter){
        return "<button class='removeControlGroup'>X</button> " + aggStageDropDown(counter);
    });

    counter = counter + 1;

    // Function to delete control group.
    $(".removeControlGroup").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });

    // add drop down next to control
    $("select").change(function() {
        $(this).parent().append(varDropDown); 

        console.log($(this).parent());
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$("select")` expression will select *all* `<select>` elements currently on the page, not only the one that was just added. Therefore 'change' handlers will accrue in previously attached `<select>` elements and will give the multiple effect that you have observed.

You can code the whole thing more efficiently with expressions of the general form :

```
$("htmlString").appendTo("container").find("someElement").method(...);
```

This avoids the need for unique ids for rediscovering elements in the DOM.

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var aggStageDropDown = "<select class='aggStage'><option value='unselected'>(Select One)</option><option value='group'>Group</option><option value='match'>Match</option><option value='unwind'>Unwind</option><option value='sort'>Sort</option></select>";
    var varDropDown = "<select><option value='var1'>var1</option><option value='var2'>var2</option><option value='var3'>var3</option></select>";

    // First elements in HTML
    var $container = $("<div class='container'></div>").appendTo("body");

    $("<button class='addGroup'>Add More Fields</button>").appendTo($container).click(function() {
        $("<div class='controlGroup'><button class='removeControlGroup'>X</button> " + aggStageDropDown + "</div>").appendTo($(this).closest(".container")).find(".removeControlGroup").click(function() {
            $(this).closest("div").remove();
        }).end().find("select.aggStage").change(function() {
            $(this).parent().append(varDropDown);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent showing [New Field] multiple times you could add following condition:

```
 $("select").change(function() {
    if ($(this).siblings("select").length) return;
    $(this).parent().append(varDropDown); 

    console.log($(this).parent());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
//add drop down next to control
$("select").change(function() {
    $(this).parent().append(varDropDown); 

    console.log($(this).parent());
});
```

which you can change to

```
// add drop down next to control
$("select").change(function() {
    if($(this).parent().find('select').length === 1){
        $(this).parent().append(varDropDown); 
    }

    console.log($(this).parent());
});
```

Which is stating that every time the select changes, add a new dropdown. If you only want there to be one

```
<select>
    <option value='var1'>var1</option>
    <option value='var2'>var2</option>
    <option value='var3'>var3</option>
</select>
```

then you need to say that you only want to add a select if it isn't there already.

Also, your code is creating duplicate Id's which you don't want. The final solution for what I believe you wanted is (and I made the id's be unique)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

aggStageDropDown = function(counter) {
    return "<select id='aggStage-operation" + counter + "'>\
        <option value='unselected'>(Select One)</option>\
        <option value='group'>Group</option>\
        <option value='match'>Match</option>\
        <option value='unwind'>Unwind</option>\
        <option value='sort'>Sort</option>\
    </select>\
    "; 

}

varDropDown = function(counter) {
    return "<select>\
        <option value='var1'>var1</option>\
        <option value='var2'>var2</option>\
        <option value='var3'>var3</option>\
    </select>\
    ";
}

// First elements in HTML
$("body").append("<div class='container'></div>")
$(".container").append("<button class='addGroup'>Add More Fields</button>");

var counter = 1;

$(".addGroup").click(function() {

    // Add a <div>, this will contain each group of form elements.
    $(".container").append(function(){
        return "<div class='controlGroup' id='aggStage" + counter + "'></div>";
    });

    // For each .controlGroup, add removeControlGroup button and add drop-down menu.
    $("#aggStage" + counter).html(function(){
        return "<button class='removeControlGroup'>X</button> " + aggStageDropDown(counter);
    });

    counter = counter + 1;

    // Function to delete control group.
    $(".removeControlGroup").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });

    // add drop down next to control
    $("select").change(function() {
        if($(this).parent().find('select').length === 1){
            $(this).parent().append(varDropDown); 
        }

        console.log($(this).parent());
    });
});
});
```